# Unified Code Counter C/C++ Counting Rules

Tags: c++, c

USC's UCC (http://csse.usc.edu/ucc_wp/) has counting rules in their documentation if you download from the link. The counting rule in question here concerns "DECLARATION OR DATA LINES" and is boxed in red, below

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why these two seemingly similar struct declarations have different SLOC (source lines of code) counts?

Comment: I guess the first case you are defining a struct with the Name A. (Defining a struct) In the second case you are defining a struct without Name, but create an Instance of it with the name A. (Defining a struct and declaring a variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, the second rule you highlighted is actually equivalent to the rule when you declare a named struct and a variable of that (name struct) type, which appears slightly below your highlighting. It just looks similar to a "pure" struct declaration (the first rule you highlighted).

Basically, it's saying "one line for the struct type definition, named or unnamed, and one line for variable declaration, regardless of its type".

Answer (score 0):

Note That

```
struct {

}var_name;
```

is different from

```
struct struct_name{

};
```

because the first one declares a sort of one-time-use struct which you can refers to using the name *var_name*.
The second one declare a struct with name *struct_name* but it does not declare any variable of that kind.

In this context using the first syntax you are performing two operations: declaring a struct and a variable of that type, so it gets a count of two.